# Rotate Binary File on Linux

Tags: linux, binaryfiles, logrotate

I've been trying to use logrotate to rotate a binary file based on size, but the program does not seem to work with binary files. For what it's worth, here's the configuration that I'm using for this specific file:

```
<filepath> {
  copytruncate
  compress
  missingok
  size 10M
  rotate 100
  nomail
}
```

Can anyone suggest a program that can handle binary files and has the same basic features as logrotate ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

in fact logrotate can handle binary files - I use logrotate to rotate database dumps - i.e.

```
/backups/mysql/mydatabase.sql.gz {
   rotate 7
   nomissingok
   create
   nocompress
   nocopy
   prerotate
   test -x /usr/bin/mysqldump || exit 1
   test -x /bin/gzip || exit 1
   mysqldump --user=xyz --password='*****' mydatabase | gzip -q -7 > /backups/mysql/mydatabase.sql.gz
   endscript
}
```

read this for more information: http://www.rackspace.com/knowledge_center/article/understanding-logrotate-utility

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution can be:

```
/var/lib/grafana/grafana.db {
  daily
  rotate 30
  nocompress
  nocreate
  copy
  olddir /data/grafana-backup/
}
```